# How to check WSUS server updates downloaded size?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, wsus, windows-update

How can I check the updates size which were downloaded in WSUS?

For example I need to check the updates size downloaded of April 9, 2013 for new 26 updates.

And how can I locale the new updates on the HDD?
Note: I have configured WSUS to automatic approval rules.
More information I have search in Google and I have found this following site

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverwsus/thread/400d1fea-c155-4add-aa16-7be2185e066e/

But unfortunately there is no answer to my question!
Any advice would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To identify the size of the file(s) associated with an update, select the update from an Update View, right click, and choose File Information. In addition to file sizes, the File Information dialog also gives you the filename and pathname of the physical file on the WSUS server.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for your quick reply. In fact how to specify a fixed date? in my example I need to check the updates of 9th April, when I have selected all I can't see file information! and this is easier for me to make a report about internet bandwidth. can you help please? thanks again.